# creating an enum with an optional value

Tags: objective-c

I'm working with some code that lays out sections for accessing an array by using an enum such as:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ReportSection) {
    Section1,
    Section2,
    Section3,
    Count
};
```

However I need to modify it to add a new row if `[self _test]` evaluates to true. The conditional is determined in runtime so I don't think I can use a macro. The resulting code will be:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ReportSection) {
    Section1,
    Section2,
    NewRow // must be between section 2 and three
    Section3,
    Count
};
```

I'm working with existing code so modifications should be kept to a minimum. If I just always use the second case with the optional row always included, I get off by one errors.

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this without going through the code and incrementing the enum values if the conditional is true (I know this is a possibility but I was hoping that a more elegant solution existed)?

Thanks for the help, I apologize if it seems rather trivial.

Comment: Why does `NewRow` need to be between `Section2` and `Section3`? That could cause a lot of problems with existing code—just making sure you know that.

Comment: This shouldn't be tagged `c`.

Comment: The enum is used to reference values in a array that represents rows in a view. The rows must be in a particular order, and newRow has to be between 2 and 3 (I know annoying). @Fiddling bits, you're right, I'll remove it.

Comment: you want something more dynamic, which is not enum. just use array of values.

Comment: The existing code references Section<1-3> which cannot be changed.

Comment: Enums are basically type declarations for integer values. What integer values shall `Section2` and `Section3` be in each variant?

Comment: In the first, Section 2 and 3 should be 1 and 2 respectively. If _test evaluates to true, they need to be 1 and 3, with 2 being NextRow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, objective-C does not allow for dynamically assignable enums. I have two options however it sounds like both require refactoring your code. Either change the values in the enum to properties and assign them during runtime, e.g.

```
@property NSUInteger Section1;
@property NSUInteger Section2;
....
```

or create as struct with the same values, initializing the struct when you initialize whatever it is that will optionally contain the optional `newRow`.

Your code should not be so brittle that it relies on an enum and breaks if it required any modifications. Take this as on opportunity to make something more robust.

Comment: I was afraid of that. This is gonna be annoying.